# Views posts not displaying correctly until clearing the cache

Tags: 8, views, caching

I have an issue with a Drupal 8 website. I have some pages that have views listing some contents ( text and images). The websites uses CDN and varnish. The problem is that sometimes, the contents like images in the views display two times bigger on the page and things are scattered all over until I clear the cache (refreshing the page does not solve the issue) and only then everything displays correctly. Every time a content is modified in the back office, the views misbehaves again until I clear the cache again.

Also I have tried to inspect the page and I see  the HTML is a different when the page does not loads correctly so it seems it's not related to CSS. The structure of the HTML changes back to normal as soon as I clear the cache.

Anyone had this issue before? I tried to disable the cache of views in the settings of the back office, but it did not solve the issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that you have cache purge modules properly configured to invalidate content in Varnish? In what way is the HTML different? There isn't much to go on here.